# Is that possible to add SPFX webpart App at toplevel and access the webpart in all subsites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

My clients want my SPFX web part in many sub sites. For this, I have to add the app to each subsite. Is there a way to add the SPFX web part app at the top level and I should be able to add web part of that app in all subsite. something like global access.

Please help me with this whether it is possible or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi all I got the answer from Sharepoint git site.

SPFX new release has the tenant-scoped deployment feature.

If you are deploying the app with this method, then no need to add the app to any site collection. The web part will be directly available for all the sites.

Below are the git hub and tutorial link.

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/849#issuecomment-328815450

https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/tenant-scoped-deployment

Comment: That's great. Didn't knew it applied to sub sites as well. A very welcome feature.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge this out-of-the box is not possible.

If I were to build this today the following two pieces would come in handy:

- [CSOM to add an add-in to a sub site](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Guidance/blob/master/articles/feature-stapling-sharepoint-add-in.md) (alternative ways might exist, like the [PnP provisioning framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/pnp-provisioning-framework) which might be able to do this)
- an event receiver running above CSOM for new sub sites - unfortunately classic event receivers don't exist and there is no [Microsoft Graph Webhook](https://developer.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/webhooks) yet to get called when new sub sites are created, so a workaround must be found

Workaround for detecting new sub sites, each a complete solution:

- create a provisioning process for sub sites that is under your control - add the add-in as part of the process (maybe you can [hook into the "Create subsite" link](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Guidance/blob/master/articles/site-provisioning-sharepoint-add-in.md#override-the-create-sub-site-link))
- create a "timer job" like piece of code in Azure polling for new sub sites - add the add-in if one is found

Time consuming. If somebody knows easier ways please chime in.

Comment: As Raghavendra pointed out, we released the tenant-wide deployment feature a short while ago.  If you don't need to execute feature XML on a specific site to use the webpart, you can make it available everywhere.